# Can polarplot take more than one array?

Tags: matlab

I need to show several radial vectors in one polar graph, but polarplot takes one array only. Is it possible to have a polar graph with multiple radial vectors?
I have already tried to create another array which contains both Z and Z1, but it doesn't work: in the graph Z and Z1 are linked creating some kind of polygon.

```
Z = [ 0, 2+3i];
Z1 = [0, 2 -1i];
p = polarplot(Z, '-');
%can't plot Z and Z1 in the same graph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MATLAB page for [polarplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html):

```
polarplot(theta,rho)
polarplot(theta,rho,LineSpec)
polarplot(theta1,rho1,...,thetaN,rhoN)
polarplot(theta1,rho1,LineSpec1,...,thetaN,rhoN,LineSpecN)
```

> `polarplot(theta1,rho1,...,thetaN,rhoN)` plots multiple rho,theta
> pairs.
> `polarplot(theta1,rho1,LineSpec1,...,thetaN,rhoN,LineSpecN)` specifies
> the line style, marker symbol, and color for each line.

However, given that it looks like you're trying to plot complex numbers, that's not what polar plot it for.  Polar plot is expecting a vector of angles and a corresponding vector of distances from the origin.

Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?  If you are trying to plot a number in the complex plane you can try something like:

```
plot(real(z), imag(Z), '-', real(Z1), imag(Z1), '--')
```

Comment: I need to plot something like this: https://www.goldensoftware.com/images/products/Grapher/polar_vector.png
Yes, I meant to plot distances and angles, but using complex numbers. Is it wrong? (I found it in official the matlab examples.)